# Cookies created on server aren't visible in Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, cookies, azure-web-app-service

I'm using ASP.NET Core 3.1 Razor pages hosted on Azure.  I'm creating a cookie with the following code.  I can't see it in Chrome Dev Tools even after a page refresh.

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public void OnGet()
    {
        CookieOptions options = new CookieOptions
        {
            Path = "/",
            Domain = "",
            HttpOnly = true,
            Secure = true,
            SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict,
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30)
        };

        Response.Cookies.Append("myCookie", "choco chip", options);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd check the network response (on the Network tab in Chrome Inspector) for the `Set-Cookie` header.

Comment: Do you have a chance to check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because you set `domain=""` in the cookie option. so after you publish to Azure, even the response set cookie correctly, the cookie will not be sent along with the request.

The solution is just to delete `domain=""` to make "domain" unspecified.

Comment: That did NOT work.  Am I the only person who creates cookies on ASP.NET Core?  How can this be so impossible?